# Flight compensation: how to calculate the distance?

Tags: delays, missed-flights, ec261

Recently, I had a delayed flight which caused me to miss a connecting flight. For making the claim under EC261, I wonder which distance I should take into account. Do I take the distance of the individual flights of the distance of the entire journey?
I see multiple ways to calculate the distance:

- Take the distances of the flight that was actually delayed. So just the first flight.
- Take the sum of the distances of the individual flights.
- Take the distance of the entire journey (straight line from departure to final destination, ignoring the intermediate stops).

In my case the two individual flights are well below 1500 km, while the total journey was well above 1500 km. The addition of the intermediate stop for calculating the total distance doesn't matter in my case, but an answer that makes the distinction would of course be more interesting.

From the spirit of the regulation, which takes into account the delay at the final destination, I would say that it is a version of the total distance. But when I look on the [website of the EU](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm), they speak all the time about distance of the **flight** and not distance of the journey.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the duplicate. Upvoted question and answer there.